# How to redefine the maximum number of decoys in a nmap scan?

Tags: nmap

I want to do a scan with a high number of decoys, I am using the following command

`nmap -D RND:252 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

But it gives the following message

`You are only allowed 128 decoys (if you need more redefine MAX_DECOYS in nmap.h)
QUITTING!`

I haven't found that file anywhere and a internet search did not return anything helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nmap.h is a header file. You will find the default nmap.h in the [github repo](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/nmap.h).

To change the maximum number of decoys you need to compile and install from source code. If you already have done, you can just go to the directory with the source code, edit nmap.h, then compile and you're done.

If you installed a package you will need to get the source code from https://nmap.org/download.html You can then either remove the package or install the latest one alongside the package by passing the --prefix option to configure and install it where it will not get in your way. nmap compilation and installation has been pretty painless for me. On FreeBSD the only dependencies are gnupg (To verify the tarball) and gmake (for building nmap). On Linux I believe you just need a build environment, on Debian the package build-essential should be all you need.

There is a book on nmap with a lot of good information. Here is the chapter on compilation and installation https://nmap.org/book/inst-source.html

Comment: Does that mean that if I want to alter it I have to compile it by hand?